# How to get a rotation matrix from final vector?

Tags: 3d, linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

I have a plane in 3D space, and I need a rotation matrix which makes the normal vector of the plane to be paralleled with z-axis. The shape of the plane should not change. How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved a problem based on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476311.

```cpp
#include "glm/matrix.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void getTransformMat(glm::vec4 before, glm::vec4 after, glm::mat4& outTransformMat, glm::mat4& outInverseTransformMat)
{
    /// https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/calculate-rotation-matrix-to-align-vector-a-to-vector-b-in-3d
    if (before[3] != 0 || after[3] != 0)
        return;
    before /= glm::length(before);
    after /= glm::length(after);
    glm::vec3 v = glm::cross(glm::vec3(before), glm::vec3(after)); 
    float c = glm::dot(before, after);
    glm::mat3 skewV(0, v[2], -v[1], 
                    -v[2], 0, v[0], 
                    v[1], -v[0], 0);
    float s = 1.0 / (1.0 + c);
    glm::mat3 R = glm::mat3(1.0) + skewV + skewV * skewV * s;
    outTransformMat = glm::mat4(R);
    outInverseTransformMat = glm::transpose(outTransformMat);
}

int main(const int argc, char** argv)
{
    glm::vec4 p1, p2, p3, p4, norm;
    p1 = glm::vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    p2 = glm::vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    p3 = glm::vec4(sqrt(0.5), 1, -sqrt(0.5), 1);
    p4 = glm::vec4(sqrt(0.5), 0, -sqrt(0.5), 1);

    norm = getPlaneNorm(p1, p2, p3);

    glm::mat4 transform, invTransform;
    getTransformMat(norm, glm::vec4(0, 0, -1, 0), transform, invTransform);
    
    std::vector<glm::vec4> calcSpaceVertices;
    glm::vec4 calcNorm;
    calcSpaceVertices.push_back(transform * p1);
    calcSpaceVertices.push_back(transform * p2);
    calcSpaceVertices.push_back(transform * p3);
    calcSpaceVertices.push_back(transform * p4);
    calcNorm = transform * norm;

    std::cout << "[Origin Points]" << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", p2.x, p2.y, p2.z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", p3.x, p3.y, p3.z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", p4.x, p4.y, p4.z);

    std::cout << "\n[Origin Normal]" << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", norm.x, norm.y, norm.z);

    std::cout << "\n[Transform]" << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f, %f\n %f, %f, %f, %f\n %f, %f, %f, %f\n %f, %f, %f, %f)\n", 
    transform[0][0], transform[0][1], transform[0][2], transform[0][3], 
    transform[1][0], transform[1][1], transform[1][2], transform[1][3], 
    transform[2][0], transform[2][1], transform[2][2], transform[2][3], 
    transform[3][0], transform[3][1], transform[3][2], transform[3][3]);

    std::cout << "\n[After Points]" << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[0].x, calcSpaceVertices[0].y, calcSpaceVertices[0].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[1].x, calcSpaceVertices[1].y, calcSpaceVertices[1].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[2].x, calcSpaceVertices[2].y, calcSpaceVertices[2].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[3].x, calcSpaceVertices[3].y, calcSpaceVertices[3].z);

    std::cout << "\n[After Normal] " << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcNorm.x, calcNorm.y, calcNorm.z);

    calcSpaceVertices[0] = (invTransform * calcSpaceVertices[0]);
    calcSpaceVertices[1] = (invTransform * calcSpaceVertices[1]);
    calcSpaceVertices[2] = (invTransform * calcSpaceVertices[2]);
    calcSpaceVertices[3] = (invTransform * calcSpaceVertices[3]);
    calcNorm = invTransform * calcNorm;

    std::cout << "\n[Return Points to origin]" << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[0].x, calcSpaceVertices[0].y, calcSpaceVertices[0].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[1].x, calcSpaceVertices[1].y, calcSpaceVertices[1].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[2].x, calcSpaceVertices[2].y, calcSpaceVertices[2].z);
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcSpaceVertices[3].x, calcSpaceVertices[3].y, calcSpaceVertices[3].z);

    std::cout << "\n[Return Normal to origin] " << std::endl;
    printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", calcNorm.x, calcNorm.y, calcNorm.z);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output
[Origin Points]
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
(0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
(0.707107, 1.000000, -0.707107)
(0.707107, 0.000000, -0.707107)

[Origin Normal]
(-0.707107, 0.000000, -0.707107)

[Transform]
(0.707107, 0.000000, 0.707107, 0.000000
 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000
 -0.707107, 0.000000, 0.707107, 0.000000
 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000)

[After Points]
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
(0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
(1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)

[After Normal]
(0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000)

[Return Points to origin]
(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)
(0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000)
(0.707107, 1.000000, -0.707107)
(0.707107, 0.000000, -0.707107)

[Return Normal to origin]
(-0.707107, 0.000000, -0.707107)
```